# Skipping validation on create method

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I need to skip the validation on create method.I am using Rails 4 and ruby 2

i have tried like this

```
@model.save(:validate => false)
```

it not working

Comment: How is `@model.save(:validate => false)` not working? What version of Rails are you using?

Answer (score 13):

Assuming you are talking about `ActiveRecord`; In Rails 3 and 4 the way to skip validations and potentially persist invalid objects is as you describe:

```
@model.save(:validate => false)
```

In Rails 2 you'd need to do

```
@model.save(false)
```

Answer (score 4):

You can do this in model by

```
validates :some_attr, :presence => true, :on => :update
```

Comment: it should be validates not validate.... validate use for custom validation...though vote up

Comment: For that you can use some virtual attribute and set it while creating and doing validation in your model like this validates :some_attr, :presence => true, :if => Proc.new { virtual_attr.present? }

Comment: save(validate: false) also dosn't work, i am using activeldap

Comment: Yeah, the solution i have provided in my third comment will work for any source

Answer (score 1):

```
validates :some_attr, :presence => true, :unless => :create
```

skips the validation JUST for create.